# Ionic Native Geolocation Promise always pending

Tags: android, geolocation, ionic3

I created a simple app which should locate device on google maps.
My code follows official docs -
 https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/.

When I run ionic in browser (with `ionic serve`) it works as expected, no errors.

But when I run my app on real android device the promise never resolved nor rejected, though I am sure permission for location is granted.

```
this.geostate = 'asking';
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
        const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.geostate = 'coordinates ready';
        processCoordinatesSomehow(latitude, longitude);
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.geostate = 'error';
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
```

In browser it switches as expected.
But on android it always the same `this.geostate === 'asking'`.

For experiment reasons, in android settings for my app I set location permission to 'ask' mode.
When I tried to get location via calling appropriate method my smartphone showed me modal window asking for location permission.
I granted it, but nothing happened - `this.geostate === 'asking'`.

Why promise from geolocation not resolved nor rejected on android but works fine in browser?

*rebuild app not helped at all

Comment: I'd have a look here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation and see if any of the android quirks gives you a clue as to why it's not working Also the W3C spec on Geolocation. https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

Comment: geolocation options timeout maybe.. getCurrentPosition({timeout:n}). Or something like this...